# Move multiple child objects with parent in Unity + LeanTouch

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, gameobject

I am facing some issues using LeanTouch asset.

**Context:**
I am creating a Human Anatomy application using **Unity3D** and **Vuforia**. My task here is to enable user to select, drag, move human skeleton and different organs to inspect them. I was able to achieve this as long as my GameObject does not have any parent.

*For example*, I have a Heart 3D model having 3 child gameobjects. If i use leantouch's selectable and other drag translate. It works with no issues. But as soon as i apply the same components to the parent Heart Object. It does not work.

If you want to try it out. Create 2 or 3 3D cube objects in unity. Then create an empty gameobject and place 3d cubes into it. Now try to add lean touch components to the parent gameobject. It won't work.

Thanks

Comment: any updates? did you ever find the correct solution for this scenario?